# Can't apply CSS to Views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor, styles

I have problem with styles in my ASP.NET MVC app.

That's my head tag in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

`site.css` is my CSS file, the problem is that I have a home view (`index.cshtml`) which has only divs inside. It renders but none of my styles work with it.

But when I type styles locally like:

```
<div class="middle" style="width:500px; height:200px;">
```

then they are applied to the div.

Do I need to set styles in every view, or is there way to make views use `_Layout` styles?

Comment: what is the content of the .css files?

Comment: Are you able to see your css file in chrome dev tools source tab.

Comment: @albjerto first is bootstrap and second:

`body {
    margin-top:40px;
}

.navbar-brand{
    height: 100px;
}

img{
    height:70px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 200px;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: white;
    border-color: white;
}

li{
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25px;
    margin-top:25px;
}

.navbar-nav{
    height:100px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 700px;
}

.banner{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
}`
.banner is class which i set for div in Home View

Comment: @satvikchoudhary yes but don't see .banner class styles i set for View.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, I assume your application is an Asp.net 5/6 or Asp.net core MVC application, right?

If that is the case, please check the index.cshtml page, whether it specify a layout by setting `Layout` property. Code like this:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

If still not working, open the Views folder, the structure should like this:

[image]

The _Layout page is in the **Shared** folder, and under the **Views** folder, we should also add the _ViewImports.cshtml page with the following content:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

and add the _ViewStart.cshtml page with the following content:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

After that, in the MVC view pages, we can use the Layout property to specify the layout page.

Finally, if the style still not working, try to use F12 developer tools to check whether the CSS file is load success, if not check the file path is correct or not. And in the Program.cs file (for Asp.net 6) or the Startup.cs file(Asp.net core 1~3 or Asp.net 5), enable the [Static files middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Code like this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

You can check this screenshot: this is an Asp.net 6 MVC application.

[image]

More detail information about layout, see [Layout in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the browser need to refresh the view without cache, I just refreshed the chrome with cntrl + f5 and the style sheet applied